# Hive and Pig on top of same dataset

Tags: hive, apache-pig

Lets say: I have a table associated with a hive structure. Can I create a pig schema over this table data? Will hive query and pig schema -both be workable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will need [HCatalog](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore#HCatalogLoadStore-HCatLoader).In Pig Shell run the below command to import the necessary jars.

```
pig -useHCatalog
```

Then load the table into a relation like this

```
A = LOAD 'tablename' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```